# Firestore throws 'onSnapshot() requires between 1 and 4 arguments'

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get all current user unread messages from the firebase. The problem is that my `onSnapshot()` returns the following error but it return my required value on initial load. If new document gets added the `onSnapshot(`) is not firing again beacuase of that error

> FirebaseError: Function Query.onSnapshot() requires between 1 and 4
> arguments, but was called with 0 arguments.

This is the helper function that receives all current user unread messages.

```
async getUnseenMessagesCount() {
    const collectionRef = (await firestore()).collection(this.collectionPath) //chats/${user_id+second_identifier/messages}
    let allMessagesCount = 0
    let currentUserReadMessagesCount = 0
    try {
      collectionRef.onSnapshot().then(snapshot => {
        allMessagesCount = snapshot.docs.length
      })
      collectionRef
        .where('seenBy', '==', '') // compare against empty string because seenBy is userId.
        .onSnapshot()
        .then(snapshot => {
          currentUserReadMessagesCount = snapshot.docs.length
        })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }

    console.log(allMessagesCount)
    console.log(currentUserReadMessagesCount)
    console.log(allMessagesCount - currentUserReadMessagesCount)
  }
```

Since I want to get all unread messages count from all chats user participates in I do the following inside my vuex action which activates on auth state change:

```
new UserChatsDB(newUser.id).readAll().then(snapshot => { //users/id/chats/{chat_id: user_id+second_identifier}
        if (snapshot.length > 0) {
          snapshot.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element)
            const count = new MessagesDB(
              element.chat_id
            ).getUnseenMessagesCount()
            console.log(count) //Returns pending Promise
          })
        }
      })
```

What can cause the error above? Is there better approach to this? Let me know if the database structure is necessary. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you forgot the `return` statement?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer Where exactly do you think there should be `return` statement?

Comment: Since you want to get the unread messages I would put it before the second `collectionRef`, where you are querying for the document that are unread. But not really sure if this solves the problem.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer I did try that, sadly it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you also put a `return` to this line `currentUserReadMessagesCount = snapshot.docs.length`?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer Yep, I tried both of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199360/discussion-between-tarvo-maesepp-and-constantin-beer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes) of firebase you have to use the `onSnapshot()` function like this:

```
async getUnseenMessagesCount() {
    const collectionRef = (await firestore()).collection(this.collectionPath) //chats/${user_id+second_identifier/messages}
    let allMessagesCount = 0
    let currentUserReadMessagesCount = 0
    try {
      collectionRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        allMessagesCount = snapshot.docs.length
      })
      collectionRef
        .where('seenBy', '==', '') // compare against empty string because seenBy is userId.
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          currentUserReadMessagesCount = snapshot.docs.length
        })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }

    console.log(allMessagesCount)
    console.log(currentUserReadMessagesCount)
    console.log(allMessagesCount - currentUserReadMessagesCount)
  }
```

So you have to remove your `then()`.